# Use session as source of field for dynamic data column

Tags: session, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have a Dynamic Data column that I want to be populated by a field from the Session collection.  (So that when the user chooses to manipulate data related to that column, where necessary, they will see information based on that field, which is stored in session).

Is there an attribute I need to use, or create?

Answer (score 1):

I have had success creating an extended property in the metadata :

```
   public partial class MyTable
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        public string MyValueFromSession
        {
            get
            {
                return Session["theAttribute"].ToString();  
            }
        }
    }
```

then you can specify a new column called MyValueFromSession in the MyTable metadata.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm, this is an interesting answer, I ended up going into the code-behind for the various PageTemplates and implementing an event handler for the linq datasource's onselecting event.

Comment: It doesn't quite work I think though because I wanted existing fields on the table to be filled in with a value resident in the Session object.

Comment: Your question says the value is stored in a session, but you want to store that session variable value in an existing column in a database table? Is that what you are trying to do?